# Prove the special unitary Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ is 3-dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

: Consider the special unitary Lie algebra
$$\mathfrak{su}(2) = \{A ∈ \mathfrak{gl}_2(\Bbb{C}) | A + A^∗ = 0, tr A = 0\} , A^∗= \overline{A}^t$$

over $\Bbb{R}$ and a bilinear form
$$(A, B) = \frac12tr(AB^∗), A, B ∈ \mathfrak{su}(2)$$.
Show that this form is symmetric. Show that $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ is 3-dimensional and has an orthonormal
basis $iσ_1, iσ_2, iσ_3$, where
$$σ_1 = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\
1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, σ_2 = \begin{pmatrix}0 & -i\\
i & 0 \end{pmatrix}  σ_3 = 
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\
0 &-1 \end{pmatrix}$$
are called Pauli matrices.

I've gotten as far as proving its symmetric, by just using general examples for A and B, and equating them. I have no idea how to prove it is 3-dimensional, or that it has such a basis. My only background in this topic is in groups and fields, and some linear algebra, so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'general examples for $A$ and $B$', but there should be no computation involved for the first part. For the dimensionality, write down the condition on the $A_{ij}$ for some $A\in {\mathfrak{gl}}(n)$ to lie in $\mathfrak{su}(n)$; the equations are linear, so just count the dimension.

Comment: For general examples I meant exactly write in the conditions and give archetypal examples for them, then just apply the bilinear form to them. I realise there are other ways to do it though. Also this way seemingly took the work out for me for the dimension question, got it in the end, thanks.

Comment: You mean writing out $A$ and $B$ as arbitrary elements of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, then computing $(A, B)$ in terms of the $A_{ij}$ and $B_{ij}$? All you need to do here is note that $X^* = -X$ on $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ and use the fact that trace is symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

For the question in the title you only need to use the definition of vector space dimension. The three matrices $i\sigma_1,i\sigma_2,i\sigma_3$ are a vector space basis of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, so that $\dim \mathfrak{su}(2)=3$ over $\mathbb{R}$. To see this, note that they are linearly independent and span the vector space.
Using a Lie algebra isomorphism, we see that $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{so}(3)$, which consists of skew-symmetric $3\times 3$ matrices. In this case it is perhaps even more obvious to see that this vector space has real dimension $3$. Write the $3\times 3$ matrices as vectors in $9$-dimensional space and determine a basis.